# Software for converting *.qmg files to *.png files

Tags: windows, media-converter, image-conversion

I've searched a lot to find a tool to convert `.qmg` files to `.png`, I didn't find a good source that's why I post a question here

- what is qmg file ?

  QMG files are included as part of a Samsung mobile phone theme. Samsung themes are created
  using the Samsung Theme Designer application. When a designer exports a theme, QMG files
  are compiled and packaged into an SMT file along with an XML file that specifies where the 
  QMG files are displayed in the theme
- what is png file ?

  Portable Network Graphics (PNG ), is a raster graphics file format that supports 
  lossless data compression. PNG was created as an improved, non-patented replacement for 
  Graphics Interchange Format (GIF), and is the most used lossless image compression 
  format on the Internet.

Comment: Does the converter have to run on Android (as you added the [tag:android] tag)? Any other possible OS?

Comment: Did you read the tag description? This tag should be used if the solution has to *run* on Android, not if it’s *related* to Android (which I also explained in my edit comment).

Comment: I'd love to know this too, except preferably as a Linux command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called Qmg2Png which can convert ".qmg" files to PNGs. The limitation ( probably )is that it depends on the android device to implement low level conversion.

That is to say, your ( presumably Samsung's )phone must include native libraries that implement the loading of QMG image into android bitmap object. As the format is proprietary, it's editing program doesn't seem to be available. 
[image: The UI of qmg2png]
With this app, conversion to PNG is possible, but reverse of that seems very difficult.

[The XDA thread for app](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/themes-apps/app-qmg2png-tool-t3360303/)

Comment: On a side note, I seek to convert PNGs to QMG, if you find a way to do that, do inform me please.